# How I can use 2.1.8 extension on magento 2.2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, magento2.2.3

I want to know that is something about structure changed in magento 2.2 that extension of magento 2.1.8 (tested) not working on it ? I have to change something to run on it ?

Comment: As far i know there is no change in module structure , did you tried to use that extension in V-2.2 ?

Comment: @inrsaurabh yes I ran  and some weird errors happen like  Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class TemplateMonster\Megamenu\Model\Attribute\Backend\Configurator does not exist

Comment: Share your complete error log , so that someone can see and i think it related to `TemplateMonster\Megamenu\` you can contact them too if you can.

Answer (score 2):

Learner
if your extension after install in Magento2.2 getting a synchronization related error so you can first make upgrade data script and use can save Json format data like -:

```
{"type":"Magento\\Rule\\Model\\Action\\Collection","attribute":null,"operator":"=","value":null}


public function serializeFun($value)
{
    $objManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $productMetadata = $objManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ProductMetadataInterface');
    if ($productMetadata->getVersion() > '2.2.0') {
        $serialize = $objManager->create('Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json');
        $conditions = $serialize->unserialize($value->getConditionsSerialized());
    } else {
        $conditions = unserialize($value->getConditionsSerialized());
    }
    return $conditions;
}
```

then you have get a synchronization error first you remove indexer function in your model file after you can use json format data.

Comment: Is Possible magento 2.0.0 theme support for magento 2.1.7?

Comment: yes also use but some theme related customization required.

Comment: Can i get study material for this.

Comment: where I need to write that all things ?\

Comment: your thing write in our Model or Controller then you can write this function in our helper file and you can call any file please you can use this function.

Answer (score 0):

having no logs in the question makes it hard to indicate a certain issue so:

1. Have a look on the logs to see details about your case
2. Check [this official docs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/release-notes/backward-incompatible-changes.html) to get more details about the changes happened as there's several major changes between Magento 2.1 and 2.2